# List prime numbers up to a given number in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function in PYTHON which returns the string of all prime numbers up to a given number. But for some reason my function is returning an empty list. please let me know what i am doing wrong. Many thanks

```
def primeList(num):

    count = 0

    for i in range(2,num+1):
        prime = True
        prime_list = []

        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime = False
                break

        if prime == True:
            prime_list.append(i)
            count += 1           

    return prime_list
```

**Function calling**
primeList(20)

Comment: Move `prime_list = []` outside of all the loops, i.e. to the top of the function.

Comment: You are incrementing `count` but not using the result anywhere. Investigate the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.

Comment: Also, you only need to check if numbers in `prime_list` are divisors of your number. It'll probably ease some of the computation.

Comment: This is also good case to use for-else loops instead of using your variable `prime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prime_list = []` should be moved out of the loop:

```
def primeList(num):

    count = 0
    # move here.
    prime_list = []
    for i in range(2,num+1):
        prime = True

        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                prime = False
                break

        if prime == True:
            prime_list.append(i)

            count += 1

    return prime_list

r =  primeList(20)
print(r)
```